# How to stop function if it runs for more than 5 sec?

Tags: php, runtime

I have a function which can run for several minutes if server does not respond.

I need a method which would limit how long it can run and that it would also give me some kind of boolean feedback if it goes over the limit.

EDIT:
Script does not look very fancy it is simple function from one project`s API what is why I need to check if it running.

It looks something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset(theFunction($data)))){ //Some code}
?>
```

I just need to make theFunction() run for less than 5 sec.

And yes I am working with PHP.

I do not need that script would start over I just want to limit the runtime and skipe it if it exceeds it.

Comment: Is this an ajax function? Post the code, if you can.

Comment: Provide code. Unless you're going to make this a multithreaded app and have one thread watch the other, how you go about stopping this function depends on what the function does and how it does it.

Comment: I _guess_ that when you say 'if server does not respond' the 5 sec. time is waiting for a response, in which case setting the time limit in PHP is useless, and it matters how you connect to that server, as different implementations need different methods of setting a timeout.

Comment: @Povylas: You need to provide some code otherwise the question can not be answered.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: That will kick the whole process if it's going over.

Comment: True. But if the script was called from AJAX, the fatal error can be captured.